# Is it possible to check if "if/else" block was triggered?

Tags: python, if-statement

Currently I am working on small project, and stumbled across such question: is it possible to know if any of if/else block statements was true (without hard-coding)? So, let's say, I have this code snippet:

```
if left < 0:
    left = 0
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
elif right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
    right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
elif bottom < 0:
    bottom = 0
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
elif top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
    top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
```

Is there any way, to extract `MOVEMENT_SPEED` and write it once? As you see, it is set to zero when one of if/else blocks is true; otherwise it does not change.

> **EDIT**

While writing this post, I came up with this "solution". See below

Comment: Yes, using `else` here would be probably the most straightforward way. It's what I was going to write an answer on until I got to the second half.

Comment: Your solution is correct. you need to instantiate "MOVEMENT_SPEED" above and it will loop thru all your if else statements.

Comment: So, there is no other optimal way?

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli This scenario is almost exactly (although kind of opposite) the purpose of `else`. Is there any thing about it that doesn't work as you want?

Comment: Are you sure you should have one big `if`/`elif`/else` block? Is it possible to hit the top/bottom and left/right sides at the same time (e.g. by moving diagonally and hitting a corner)?

Comment: Setting variable to zero and again to five, kinda seems wasteful. I thought maybe there is more optimal way. Seems no) Thanks @Carcigenicate

Comment: @Blckknght yes, it moves only in one direction at a time)

Comment: I guess, I will move EDIT part as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if any check was
 true, you can flip it and make use of `else` to check if no checks were true, since `else` will only run if none of the conditions before it were true.

If you don't conceptually like setting `MOVEMENT_SPEED`, you could have a simple flag instead:

```
did_collide = True  # Defaults to True

if left < 0:
    left = 0
elif right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
    right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1
elif bottom < 0:
    bottom = 0
elif top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
    top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1
else:
    did_collide = False

if did_collide:
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
```

It's essentially the same, but it avoids reassigning (the presumably global) `MOVEMENT_SPEED` unnecessarily, which could potentially interfere with other code.

Comment: Nice one, but identical to my answer) Thanks though

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli Ya, as I noted in my edit, this is really the same idea. It just avoids reassigning the global that other functions may or may not depend on (if it is global).

Comment: Yeah, yours is more optimal. If I have multiple global vars, it is much more easier with your solution. Accepted)

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the solution I came up with so far:

```
MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
if left < 0:
    left = 0
elif right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
    right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1
elif bottom < 0:
    bottom = 0
elif top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
    top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1
else:
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
```

This works, and is better than hard-coding as shown above. Basically, set variable, and in `else` reset it (it means, none of if/else was triggered)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the surrounding context, but I suspect in this situation I'd want to break the logic of clipping the rectangle's sides to the screen into its own function, and then use that function in such a way as to make the MOVEMENT_SPEED adjustment easy:

```
from typing import Tuple


def clip_rect_to_screen(
    rect: Tuple[int, int, int, int],  # left, right, bottom, top
    screen: Tuple[int, int]           # width, height
) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int]:
    left, right, bottom, top = rect
    width, height = screen
    return (
        max(left, 0),
        min(right, width - 1),
        max(bottom, 0),
        min(top, height - 1),
    )


clipped_rect = clip_rect_to_screen(
    (left, right, bottom, top), (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
)
if (left, right, bottom, top != clipped_rect):
    left, right, bottom, top = clipped_rect
    MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0
```